# Consequences of travelling to Iran

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, iran

As a Sri Lankan, I have visa-free entry for Iran. I want to travel there in the summer, but if I do, would the visit be stamped in my passport, and if so would this affect my applying for visas in countries such as the USA or Israel or a country in the EU?
Please help.

Comment: [Visiting Israel with an Iranian visa](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/israel/visiting-israel-with-an-iranian-visa)

Comment: thanks, looks like the israelis are going to be fine with it. let's see about the others

Comment: You could consider applying for a second passport - I know that some countries give you a second passport, for exactly those reasons.

Comment: Just checked, that option is not available here @Aganju , but this is as far as the helpdesk officer's knowledge, which in this country may vary greatly, is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are traveling to Iran as a tourist then it shouldn't have any adverse affects on you getting the visa of US, Israel etc. down the line in the future. However, it is always best to consult the local consulates of different countries about the latest updates.

Comment: True in this case. Worth mentioning that but will make people ineligible for US Visa Waiver Program.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Though Sri Lanka is not part of the Visa Waiver Program. So this would not be relevant unless he has or gets a nationality that is part of the VWP.